# How not to render null?

Tags: flutter

I'm not sure if I'm asking this right but I have a List. Some have values some don't.

So in my ListTile(), if there is value (a string), it would render the value.
But if it's null, it will render the word "null".
What can I make it so the word "null" wont show?

Here is an example:

```
Text("Show value: " + cars.type.last.make);
```

`make` is the list. If it's null it will render "Show value: null".

Here is the actual code

```
return ListTile( 
   title: Text( "Data is " + cars.type.last.make);
)
```

It will render a list like this:
"Data is Red"
"Data is Blue"
"Data is null"
"Data is Green"

I want "Data is null" to not render and be a blank space like:
"Data is Red"
"Data is Blue"

"Data is Green"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
ListTile(
        title: myString == null ? Text('') : Text(myString)
      )
```

Dude's answer below is better:

```
ListTile(title: Text(myString ?? ''))
```

---

If you'd like that `ListTile` to not take up space (instead of an emptystring) you could create a method:

```
Widget _listTile(String item) => item == null ? SizedBox() : ListTile(title: Text(item));
```

And use it in your `ListView`:

```
return _listTile(cars.type.last.make);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a ternary:

```dart
return ListTile( 
   title: Text( (cars.type.last.make)? "Data is ${cars.type.last.make}" : "");
)
```

Comment: cars.type.last.make is showing an error "Conditions must have a static type of bool"
"make" is a string (sometimes null)

Comment: Try with the brackets, if not working add != null

Comment: ```Text( (cars.type.last.make != null)? ```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the code as below

```
cars.type.last.make?Text('Null'):Text("Show value: " + cars.type.last.make);
```

Answer (score -1):

The above answers are not simple and straight forward. Try using the `??` operator. It basically checks if the value on the left is `null` or no, if it is `null` then it will use the value on the right.

```
Text("Show value: " + cars.type.last.make ?? "The list is empty");
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to draw ListTile in case of null value, wrap with 'if' state.

```
if (cars.type.last.make != null)
   ListTile(child...)
```

Or if you just want to replace 'null' word to something,
using '??' null operator.

```
Text("Show value: " + cars.type.last.make ?? 'something');
```

no edits